# Getting a list from a returned hashmap

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

I have a class with a method called `prepareListData`. This method prepares data to populate an `ExpandableListView` in Android. When the method is placed within the class that calls it, it works perfectly and it does not need to return anything as I use private fields. When I move the method to its own class and make it static, I get a null pointer as it clearly needs to return the data that it prepares.

The class I created has the same method (`prepareListData`) which returns a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. I am trying to call the method from the other class from where I wish to assign the `List<>` in the returned `HashMap` to a `List<String>` variable. Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

I have never attempted this before so I have no idea where to even start.

Here is my Class with the prepareListData method:

```
public class PrepareListData {

    public static HashMap prepareListData() {
        List<String> gpsMenuListDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, List<String>> gpsMenuListDataChild = new HashMap<>();

        // Main group data
        gpsMenuListDataHeader.add("Job Card");
        gpsMenuListDataHeader.add("Sign Off");
        gpsMenuListDataHeader.add("Test Installation");

        // Child Items for Job Card
        List<String> jobcard = new ArrayList<>();
        jobcard.add("Job Card Sub Item 1");
        jobcard.add("Job Card Sub Item 2");
        jobcard.add("Job Card Sub Item 3");
        jobcard.add("Job Card Sub Item 4");
        jobcard.add("Job Card Sub Item 5");

        // Child Items fos Sign Off
        List<String> signoff = new ArrayList<>();
        signoff.add("Sign Off Sub Item 1");
        signoff.add("Sign Off Sub Item 2");
        signoff.add("Sign Off Sub Item 3");

        // Child Items for Test Installation
        List<String> testInstallation = new ArrayList<>();
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 1");
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 2");
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 3");
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 4");
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 5");
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 6");
        testInstallation.add("Test Installation Sub Item 7");

        gpsMenuListDataChild.put(gpsMenuListDataHeader.get(0), jobcard);
        gpsMenuListDataChild.put(gpsMenuListDataHeader.get(1), signoff);
        gpsMenuListDataChild.put(gpsMenuListDataHeader.get(2), testInstallation);

        return gpsMenuListDataChild;
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the method where I am trying to call and extract the List<> from the HashMap:

```
gpsMenuListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.gps_menu_drawer);
prepareListData();
gpsMenuListDataHeader = PrepareListData.prepareListData().;
gpsMenuListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, gpsMenuListDataHeader, gpsMenuListDataChild);
gpsMenuListView.setAdapter(gpsMenuListAdapter);
```

StackTrace:

```
08-26 23:12:25.031  32157-32164/za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
08-26 23:12:25.039  32157-32157/za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard, PID: 32157 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard/za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupCount(ExpandableListAdapter.java:45)
    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:397)
    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
    at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:603)
    at za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Where is the null pointer? Please show the error message.

Comment: hard to tell, but my first guess is that `gpsMenuListDataChild` is `null` ...

Comment: I have updated my question and included the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to call the method from the other class from where I wish
>   to assign the List<> in the returned HashMap to a List
>   variable. Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

```
HashMap<String, List<String> map = PrepareListData.prepareListData();
List<String> yourlist = map.get("key");
```

where key is the key that maps to the List you need. In your example, these would be one of "Job Card", "Sign Off", "Test Installation".

FYI I would suggest assigning these string constants to a variable. What happens if you need to change one? You will have to find every location it is used to change it.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your reply. This worked for me. I appreciate the help. Happy coding guys